# Null exception error while running selenium test using testng framework

Tags: java, selenium, exception, selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception

I am running selenium simple script in testng framework but I am getting null pointer exception,Please find below my code

```
package test.maven;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.*;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;

public class test {
public String baseUrl = "http://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/";
String driverPath = "C:\\geckodriver.exe";
public WebDriver driver ; 
@AfterTest                            //Jumbled
 public void terminateBrowser(){
 driver.close();
      }
     @BeforeTest                            //Jumbled
      public void launchBrowser() {
          System.out.println("launching firefox browser"); 
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
          driver.get(baseUrl);
      }
      @Test                                //Jumbled
      public void verifyHomepageTitle() {
          String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
          String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
          Assert.assertEquals(actualTitle, expectedTitle);
     }
     }
```

Comment: Can you add the stack trace? Where you are getting the NULL Pointer Exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance Webdriver Object is not intialized and Local Webdriver Object is created in Before Test method. Please change the before test as below(Remove the Webdriver)

```
 @BeforeTest                            //Jumbled
      public void launchBrowser() {
          System.out.println("launching firefox browser"); 
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
          driver.get(baseUrl);
      }
```